# Understanding use of foreign_key and class_name in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am new to rails and this is a very basic question. I am trying to understand the need of foreign key and class_name.

```
has_many :task, foreign_key: "created_by"
has_many :memberships, class_name: "TaskMembership"
```

Can anyone explain the need of **foreign_key** & **class_name**.

Comment: Those are the options to define custom class name and foreign key.

Comment: I've already said that.

Comment: still unclear...I could have written has_many :taskmemberships so ???

Comment: Refer to self joins in the guides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer of my question

Suppose you have a User model and Post model.And you have to  set an association like `User has  many post`

```
User Model
has_many :posts

Post Model
belongs_to :user
```

Now suppose your user is some author so we have to set some meaningful name so instead of user we will use author but have to specify which class it is referring

```
 Post Model
 belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
```

Now problem will occur because rails will look for author_id column in posts table .So here foreign key will come into picture.We will have to find  user_id

```
Post Model
belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
```

See more better explanation [association](https://www.sitepoint.com/brush-up-your-knowledge-of-rails-associations/)

Comment: You haven't actually answered the original question, what is the use of the foreign_key on the has_many association? To me it's confusing, I would assume only belogns_to can specify foreign_keys but rails actually accepts it on has_many as well, so what does it do?

Answer (score -1):

`has_many` association is used for for one-to-many type relationships in rails. For instance, if you have a model `User` which can has many profiles, your `User` to Profile association will be has many.

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :profiles
    end

    class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
    end
```

If you have a foreign key different than user_id in profiles table, you explicitly specify foreign_key. Same is the case with class name. If your association name is different than actual model name, you explicitly specify class name after association (as you did for memberships).
Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah i understand that class name is explicitly specified  but when we have to do that???my question how will i know when to use class_name over here

Comment: Suppose a case when you have to implement a Bank interaction system. You have a class User which is a generic class, can be used both for Bank staff and for customers. You have a communication model, and you want to store both bank staff and customer id in it. Now how will explicitly you get staff's all interactions and customer's all interaction?

Comment: Its just an example, you can have a lot of different scenarios in which you dont use ID has your foreign key in associated model.
You can have an Address model used for Bank and User both. You can say bank has_one bank_address, class_name: "Address"

Comment: @aniket When you want to create a relationship other than the conventions like `has_many :profiles` means that profile will have `user_id` columns by default but if you want to define `has_many` relationship for profile on the basis of a field other than `user_id` then you have to do it like : `has_many :profiles, foreign_key: "other_field"`

Answer (score -1):

in your model

```
class First < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :seconds
end

class Second < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :first
end
```

and in your second class table,create first_id column